# python throwing an error when I am trying to retrieve tweets based on specific terms from specific users

Tags: python, tweepy

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import tweepy
consumer_key='xyz',
consumer_secret='xyz',
access_key='xyz',
access_secret='xyz'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api=tweepy.API(auth)
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        return True
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
list_users = ['17006157','59145948','157009365','16686144','68044757','33338729']   #Some ids
list_terms = ['abc','def']   #Some terms
sapi.filter(follow=list_users, track=list_terms)
```

The output on the python shell is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/nytimes/20052014/mutliple keyword from multiple user search.py", line 44, in <module>
    sapi.filter(track=["list_terms"])
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 313, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 235, in _start
    self._run()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 151, in _run
    timeout=self.timeout, stream=True, auth=auth)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 348, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 286, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\models.py", line 290, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\models.py", line 469, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib-0.4.0-py2.7.egg\requests_oauthlib\oauth1_auth.py", line 63, in __call__
    unicode(r.url), unicode(r.method), r.body or '', r.headers)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 280, in sign
    request.oauth_params.append(('oauth_signature', self.get_oauth_signature(request)))
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 112, in get_oauth_signature
    uri, headers, body = self._render(request)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 186, in _render
    headers = parameters.prepare_headers(request.oauth_params, request.headers, realm=realm)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 32, in wrapper
    return target(params, *args, **kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\parameters.py", line 58, in prepare_headers
    escaped_value = utils.escape(value)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 57, in escape
    'Got %s of type %s.' % (u, type(u)))
ValueError: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got <generator object <genexpr> at 0x03006080> of type <type 'generator'>.
```

That is all of it.

Comment: Where is the rest of the traceback?

Comment: I am trying to post it but its saying Its code add some context can you please edit it M trying to post it..

Comment: Your whole question shouldn't be code - nor should you try to fit all of the text into the title! Please add an introductory paragraph explaining what you are trying to do, what you have tried so far, etc.

Comment: I have posted it somehow but its not in the correct format. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: seems to be a solution here: https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/issues/11

Comment: I have changed the credentials 'Consumer_key' and so on but now at python shell cursor is stuck..just showing >>>

Comment: Any help in the above regards will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like it's the commas at the end of three of your variable assignments:

```
consumer_key='xyz',
consumer_secret='xyz',
access_key='xyz',
```

The commas turn the values into tuples. For some reason the oauth lib is converting them to generators which is causing the `ValueError` to be raised.